# Error while calling transform function using object of class

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, transform

I have just started learning the spark-specific functions in python. I am writing one program that reads, transforms, and writes the data. I am using the transform function to do the transformation.

I have just started learning the spark-specific functions in python. I am writing one program that reads, transforms, and writes the data. I am using the transform function to do the transformation.

```
import logging
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


class Ingest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.spark_session = (
            SparkSession.builder.master("cluster")
            .appName("IngestData")  
            .getOrCreate()
        )
        self.input_directory = ("/mnt/input")
        self.output_directory = ("/mnt/output")

 

    def applyLogic(self):
        df.cache()

        listValues = ["X", "Y"]
        df = df.withColumn(
            "name",
            when(
                (df["Title"].contains("Gemini"))
                & (df["Title"].contains("Cancer")),
                "Intelligent"
            )
         return df




obj = Ingest()
transformedDF = obj.transform(applyLogic)
```

Getting an error while using the `transform` function. Any pointers on how to call the transform function using a class object or I am doing something wrong?I am able to run it without using the transform function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it after making the below change

```
obj = Ingest()
transformedDF = df.transform(obj.applyLogic)
```